# Predicting target variable for some a small group of a data by machine learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, boosting

This will be a general question about machine learning. Let say, I have such a data which have such variables:

- y(target variable): Salary
- x1: Age
- x2: Job
- x3: Location

Let say, I want to predict y by x1,x2 and x3 by a machine learning algorithm(random forest or gradient boosting- parameter tuning is managed).

Let say there is an true interaction in a small portion of the that data.

For example,

for:

- location: Mumbai
- Age     : 40-45
- Job     : Hair dresser

the salary is very high.  And the portion of this set is very low in the data.

However, both algortihms, random forest and gradient boosting can't accurately predict the salary for this group. This is I guess being small set and that set stays in deep of trees. I wonder, whether is that reason is true or not?

And, I wonder how can predict more accurately for such small sets, without losing the accuracy rest of the data? Is there a way to cath these interactions?

I can't  share the data here because of privacy terms.

I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: On your second question, I can't help but feel that you are asking "I want to improve the accuracy (or another performance metric) overall, but those improvement has to come from that particular subset of data points. How can I do so?", which seems not an reasonable ask. If your goal is to get that particular subset of data points correctly predicted, you can always alter your performance metric to upweight those data points. Although by doing so you will almost certainly sacrifice the accuracy (or other metric) on other points, akin to the bias-variance tradeoff.

Comment: @B.Liu thank for your comment. It seemed to me as an reasonable method. Maybe, I can combine two methods. For that set, I can use the model that predicted by weighted performance weighted metric. For the remining set, I can use another model which is modeled by unweighted performance metric. Is this a reasonable method, do you think.  I also tried such a method: I defined that set as a dummy variable. And I put that variable into the model. And that model improved my predictions by improving that set.

Comment: Now it is a different story - in both proposed methods you have (implicitly & explicitly respectively) provided the overall model with extra information, i.e. "hey, these data points are different, treat them differently", which could lead to the (overall) model improving its performance metric. Depending on your application, I will be extremely cautious on resultant (overall) model's ability to generalise onto unseen samples though, as you mentioned that "the true interaction" set of data is small.

Comment: You are right @B.Liu That set was a known set for me. It seems, if I know the set, I can improve the predictions for that specific set and also for the whole data. But, for the unseen sets, those methods are not applicable. Is there any method to discover such " small true interactions "?